# React native: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

```
Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

I tried the same code in other react-native project but the value is same.

Comment: what have you changed recently?

Comment: Nothing i was just making instagram clone with it and error pops up

Comment: The error without code or context is pretty hard to help with.  I think more detail is necessary.  You can check out [ask] for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

there might be a problem in the code like invalid fetching (In my case, wrong use of firebase query to get data). There might be wrong fetching of packages etc ( as mentioned in the official react-native git issues ). Try to check there

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).